# sass alternate color in subsequent nested elements

Tags: sass

Suppose I want to altenate the background color of a div if it is nested within another div of same classname.

Example:

```
.my-div {
    background-color: white;
    .my-div {
      background-color: grey;
      .my-div {
        background-color: white;
        .my-div {
          background-color: grey;
          .my-div {
            background-color: white;
            .my-div {
              background-color: grey;
              .my-div {
                background-color: white;
                .my-div {
                  background-color: grey;
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Is there a way to achieve this less verbosely, say to 8 levels, with a sass loop or other function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@mixin altBox($n) {
  $n: $n + 1;

  .alternator {
    @if $n % 2 == 0 {
      background: white;
    } @else {
      background: gray;
    }
    @if ($n < 9) {
      @include altBox($n);
    }
  }
}

@include altBox(0);
```

Was able to achieve it with a recursive mixin